# Files corrupted

Tags: php, google-apps-script

I have a google apps scripts app that gets Gmail message attachments, posts it to DB using JDBC. then on the server, a PHP script gets the data and puts in into a file and attaches it to an email. 

the problem is that the files are corrupt when email arrives

here is the google apps script function that gets the attachment content

```
function getMessageAttachmentsArray(msg){
   var GmailAttachments = msg.GmailMessage.getAttachments();
   var validAttachments = [];
   var attachmentNames = [];

  if(GmailAttachments)
  {
      for(i in GmailAttachments)
      {
          var gName = GmailAttachments[i].getName();
          attachmentNames.push(gName);
          var mimeType = GmailAttachments[i].getContentType();
          var size = GmailAttachments[i].getSize();
          var content = Utilities.base64Encode(GmailAttachments[i].getDataAsString(), Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);

         var push = {"content":content,"mimeType":mimeType,"fileName":gName,"size":size,"id":""};
      validAttachments.push(push);

     }
  }
  return [validAttachments, attachmentNames];
}
```

here is the PHP code that generated the email from the file data:

```
require_once 'smtpmail/classes/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPmailer(true);

$email = $argv[1];
$messageid = $argv[2];
$fax_number = $argv[3];

$attachments = array();

//get the attachments for this email
$Sql = "select * from user_attachments where email = '$email' and messageid like '$messageid%'";

$res = mysql_query($Sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $return['filename'] = $row['name'];
    $return['mime'] = $row['mime_type'];
    $content = base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($row['raw_data'], '-_', '+/'), strlen($row['raw_data']) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
    $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Fax');
    file_put_contents($temp_file, $content);
    $return['file'] = $temp_file;
    array_push($attachments, $return);
}

try{
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
    $mail->SetFrom("example@example.com", "example email");
    $mail->Subject = '';
    $mail->Body = '  '; //put in a blank body to avoid smtp error
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    foreach($attachments as $file){
        $mail->AddAttachment($file['file'], $file['filename'], 'base64' ,mime_content_type($file['file']));
    }
    if($mail->send()){
        echo "email to $email sent successfully\n";
    }else{
        echo "error sending email to $email\n";
    }
}catch(phpmailerException $e){
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

When the message is received it shows the attachments but when downloaded I can not open them and there is a message that the file is corrupt or the file extension does not match the file format

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I tried emailing the attachment without posting to the DB, by posting to the server with UrlFetchApp() and the results are the same. clearly, I am doing something wrong with Base64_encode / decode... 
maybe the google apps scripts :

```
Utilities.base64Encode(GmailAttachments[i].getDataAsString(), Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
```

creates a different base64 format than PHP base64_decode expects?

p.s. 
I tried also with and without 'str_pad' and I still got the same results.

Comment: when you check the file in db, is it ok?

Comment: Most likely it's because  the base64 has been fiddled with `base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($row['raw_data'], '-_', '+/'), strlen($row['raw_data']) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));` why you not storing it as-is?

Comment: As 'insider' suggested, follow the data from source to destination and find the step where the corruption occurs. We cannot do that, you can. It should not be difficult to isolate the problem, but you have to put in some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed:

```
Utilities.base64Encode(GmailAttachments[i].getDataAsString(), Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
```

to:

```
Utilities.base64Encode(GmailAttachments[i].getBytes());
```

and it works